# How to detect a field value change in a JSF 2.0 page

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.0 to develop a pretty big and complex page which contains numerous fields. Thre would be quit command button at the buttom of the page and when ever user selects the quit option I need to detect whether user has entered any value on one of the fields of the page.

I am using the null check of each field values in the backing bean to do that now, but that's a very tedious and repeative job. I was wondering is there any smart solution for that ?? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a Client side solution or a Server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field-values are probably linked to properties of the backing-bean. When the value is changed, the setter is invoked. Inside the setter you could set a boolean field of the bean to true, if the value actually changed.

```
public void setPropertyX(Type newValue) {
    if(!newValue.equals(this.X)) {
        this.X = newValue;
        this.fieldChanged = true;
    }
}
```

For this to work, you backing-bean should be at least in `@ViewScope`.

Answer (score 11):

For that the `valueChangeListener` attribute is meant to be used.

```
<h:inputText ... valueChangeListener="#{bean.changed}" />
```

with

```
public void changed(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    this.changed = true;
}
```