# Show dirty area (Custom warning message) dialog in JSF/ Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am working on primefaces application,

If something is changed in a page, and clicked another page without saving, I need to show a popup dialog saying that, **Hey you changed something do you want to save it or not**, Based on the user selection it should do either save/cancel/no function.

I seen the link, 
[to track the changes in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563527/how-to-detect-a-field-value-change-in-a-jsf-2-0-page),

If it is in the same bean class and clicked on cancel button, I can write some function and show this dialog.

But, if user clicked on other link/page or menu item how to handle this case.

Is there anyway like, before the flow go to any other bean the last method should be called.

As I searched because of security browsers are not showing custom warning messages.

```
@PreDestroy
public void destroy() { ..}
```

I tried this, but this method is not getting called correctly if I click on other link every time. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2):

To Capture the changes in the application, you may need to introduce the dirty Flag, If any of the component value getting changes, then application should set the dirty flag value to true. Like the below example.

```
<h:inputText id="someId" onchange="setDirty();"
    value="#{myManager.name}" maxlength="100">
```

User try to navigate the next page, without saving, then WindowBeforeUnloadListener will trigger first, just check the Boolean variable, if the value is true, show the validation popup.

```
var dirty = true;
window.onunload = windowUnloadListener;
window.onbeforeunload = windowBeforeUnloadListener;
window.onload = windowLoadListener;

/*
 * Listener for Window-Onbeforeunload event.
 * Called before unloading (leaving the current page) the window.
 * This function checks for the dirty flag and pops up the 
 * message to confirm wit the user. 
 */
function windowBeforeUnloadListener() {
   if(dirty) {
       return "You have used navigation controls that are not part of the page.\n\n 
       If you wish to end, click 'Leave this page'. "
       + "Your session will end here.\n\n"
       + "If you wish to continue to use then please click 'Stay on this page'.";
    }
}
```

On Page load and on Save, set the dirty flag value to false.

```
/*
 * Listener for Window-Onload event.
 * Called every time a new page is loaded.
 * This function will reset the flag.  
 */
function windowLoadListener(){
    dirty= true;
}
```

Note: The Custom validation message won't work in IE. It shows the default browser validation message.